# Thunar files view, date format "today, yesterday"

Tags: xubuntu, thunar

The detail view of Thunar shows the modification time as localized date (dd.mm.YYYY for my location), which is fine, but I would like to see the time, too.

And it doesn't show the recently modified files in the same manner, butnew years new years  decorates them as 'yesterday, today, monday' and so on, which is a nice programming etude, but not really useful to me.

Au contraire - it is pretty annoying to have this mixture in the interface. The next version will look into my calender and mark some files 'easter 2007, moms birthday 2002' and 'third monday of last month'. Thank you!

But if ohters prefer it - I'm fine. I just want to know whether I can modify the setting somehow. This is Xubuntu 12.04 LTS, Thunar 1.2.3.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

open Thunar and choose preferences from Edit menu . then at Display , choose the date format as you want. I am uploading the image too . [image]

hope that helps .

Comment: That easy? I'm ashamed. :)

Comment: while it's nice that there are a few choices for the format, it would be even nicer if we could also specify a custom format (e.g. using the same format syntax as the `date` command).

Comment: @Mark you would make a feature request at https://forum.xfce.org/

Comment: It is definitely a stupid decision to make these "today, yesterday" formatting as default.

Comment: @imkzh, I would say its how you prefer. its a vscode vs vim, which one you choose is upto you.