# File manager's column "Date Modified" doesn't show time?

Tags: xubuntu

I am using Xubuntu 14.04. In the File Manager, the Date Modified column doesn't show the modification time. How can I make it display the time, along with the date?

Comment: I just found the answer: http://askubuntu.com/q/233847/234374